# Integrar site wordpress com sistema externo

Tags: wordpress

Bom dia.

Estou criando um site wordpress para o cliente, e gostaria de saber se é possivel ter tal funcionalidade e o que devo fazer. Vou explicar como deve funcionar:

A empresa trabalha com importação de produtos e equipamentos, o usario que fez uma importação entra no site, se loga, estando logado ele tem acesso a uma pagina onde visualizará detalhes sobre a importação (tais como: onde se encontra a mercadoria, que data saiu do pais de origem, que data deve chegar, etc), sendo assim cada usuario verá as informações de sua mercadoria, alem de arquivos (pdf, jpg, etc) relacionados a esta.

Tais informações das mercadorias serão preenchidas em um sistema externo ao site (pela empresa que estou atendendo), logo não tenho acesso a isso. No entanto tais informações serão enviadas (em txt) para o site, este deve pegar tal arquivo txt e integrar as informações em seu banco para ser acessado pelo usuario.

Minha duvida é como fazer tal integração com um banco externo, e tambem como cada usuario terá acesso à apenas os dados referente as suas mercadorias. Até agora só sei fazer cadastro de assinantes, onde todos os usuarios tem os mesmo tipos de acessos.

Ficou claro? Preciso saber se é possivel fazer algo assim, se existem plugins ou ferramentas para ajudar nisso.

Comment: Opa bom dia, cara me parece que você quer "consumir" um serviço que vem lá do seu cliente e exibir ele numa tela do site, é isso mesmo ? Eu nunca fiz em wordpress e não manjo muito ainda, mas imagino que [isso](https://tableless.com.br/rest-json-wp-api-e-o-futuro-do-wordpress/) aqui possa te ajudar.

Comment: O que você quer é possível, mas é tão anos 70 que não vale a pena. Insista para que seu cliente se adeque a 2017 e se recuse a receber esse arquivo txt.

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer isso sem plugins ou ferramentas externas. Crie um plugin e dentro dele crie um Post Type para guardar as informações de cada importação.

**Para receber as informações:**

Isso depende de como e onde os arquivos TXT estarão acessíveis. Supondo que seja uma URL que o seu servidor consiga acessar, você pode montar um `WP Cron` que faça uma requisição à URL e faça o download dos arquivos novos. Use `wp_remote_get` pra isso.

Uma vez que os arquivos estejam no seu servidor, basta ler os conteúdos de cada um usando o PHP (p. ex com `file_get_contents`) e criar novos posts dentro do seu Post Type, preenchendo Titulo, Conteudo e outros-metadados que tiver, um para cada importação. Isso vc faz com `wp_insert_post` e `update_post_meta`.

**Para resolver as questões de permissão de acesso:**

Crie seus usuários com um nível de acesso básico, p.ex: Autor. Na hora de salvar o post acima você busca o usuário correto no banco de dados (use `get_user_by`) e coloca ele como autor do post. No seu código você restringe quais posts podem ser vistos por cada nível de usuário, e faz uma alteração global nas consultas (usando `pre_get_posts`) para que cada usuário abaixo de um certo nível (p. ex, Editor) só tenha acesso aos seus próprios posts.